# Microsoft Teams overwritten hotkeys

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I have installed Microsoft Teams application and it has overwritten hotkeys like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and doesn't allow me to change them in application settings.

The problem is that these hotkeys are reserved in Polish language for diactrical characters so if I have opened Teams application I can't use these characters.

Do you know any solution to not allow application to overwrite default hotkeys?

Comment: I know it's not an answer, but there is a workaround for this: uninstall MS Teams, install Franz and set up MS Teams account there :) works like before and there's no annoying hotkeys.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been reported to Microsoft and they say they are working on it.

You can follow progress at https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/32520820-teams-has-hijacked-several-keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: as of autumn of 2020 there is no progress and there is no workaround yet

Comment: According to the uservoice ticket mentioned above, the issue has been fixed in May 2019.

Comment: as of autumn of 2021 there is no way to override hot keys in M$ Teams yet