# Disable or prevent Teams global keyboard shortcusts

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-teams

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to add Comments in a Word document. However, with Microsoft Teams installed it captures that shortcut for Microphone Mute/Unmute, no matter if the application is running or a call is active.

Can I somehow disable that particular short cut?

I've seen: https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/33965626-disable-or-modify-keyboard-shortcuts and [Microsoft Teams overwritten hotkeys](https://superuser.com/questions/1274110/microsoft-teams-overwritten-hotkeys), but hope someone has progressed on this with either another tool or trick.

Comment: You can close Teams in the Task Manager.
I do not experience this problem if Word is opened before Teams.

Answer (score 0):

#### A workaround to your specific problem

Microsoft Word allows you to reassign its keyboard shortcuts in Options window. This way, just change the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to different key combination which is not in conflict with Microsoft Teams or any other app.